# JSF 2 DI vs CDI Java EE 6/7

Tags: java, jsf, dependency-injection, cdi

How different is JSF DI from CDI? I mean, is possible to inject all the things that we use with JSF DI (such as `FacesContext`, managed properties, etc.) with the CDI spec? There are issues or pitfalls?

Comment: CDI is much more robust than JSF CI. Dependency faults can be identified statically/at deploy time and it is less prone to scope leaks. Consider JSF CI as deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that JSF2 provides you no injection support for `FacesContext`, it seems like there may be a bigger question at play.  I believe JSF 2.2 added support for this via `@Inject`.  Managed properties cannot be injected, the expected equivalent is to provide a `@Named` bean with getters and setters properly defined and leverage that from the UI.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues, you can inject CDI beans into JSF Managed Beans or use directly. 
I heard that JSF DI will be replaced by CDI in future Java EE releases. 
You can have everything in Spring IoC container instead.